# asp mvc animate removing table row

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can I put some effects if I am going to remove my table row, for now I am just using reload() function to refresh my data.

My table is like this:

```
<table class="sortable" border="1" id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">@item.name</td>
                <td>

                    <button onclick="Remove('@item.name', '@item.age')" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Remove
                    </button>


                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    <tbody>
</table>
```

And my script to remove then refresh:

```
 function Remove(name, age) {
        var result = confirm("Are you want to remove " + name);
        if (result == true) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Remove',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id': name,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload() //---> Want to have effects rather than refresh
                    alert('Data has been successfully removed');
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onclick` handler in your HTML, pass `this`  as a parameter to your `Remove` method.

```
onclick="Remove(this, '@item.name', '@item.age')"
```

Add a new parameter to your method to accept it. When the remove button is clicked, that will be the button element.

Now use the `closest` method to get a reference to the outer table row. In your ajax method's `success` handler, you can now call the `fadeOut` method and then eventually remove the table row from the DOM.

```
function Remove(that, name, age) {
        var result = confirm("Are you want to remove " + name);
        if (result == true) {

           // Get the jQuery object of the outer TR of clicked button
           $tr = $(that).closest("tr");

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Remove',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id': name,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                     $tr.find('td').fadeOut(400,function() {
                          $tr.remove();
                     });
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: cool! its working, could  this the same if I am going to add a new row functionality as well?